# Find a power series for $\frac{z^2}{(4-z)^2}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Find a power series for $$\frac{z^2}{(4-z)^2}$$
What I did is:
Since
$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}z^k=\frac{1}{1-z}$$
Take the derivative, so
$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}kz^{k-1}=\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$$
So
$$\frac{z^2}{(4-z)^2}=\frac{z^2}{4^2(1-\frac{z}{4})^2}=\frac{z^2}{4^2}\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}k\left(\frac{z}{4}\right)^{k-1}=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}k\left(\frac{z}{4}\right)^{k+1}$$
However, the solution is 
$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{k+1}{2\cdot 4^{k}}z^{k+2}$$
Thanks for any comments~

Comment: I don't see an error in your work.

Comment: Notice that the initial term should be $z^2/16$ which does not match the official solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $|z|<4$ we have:$$\frac{1}{4-z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{4^{n+1}}\to \frac{1}{(4-z)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)z^n}{4^{n+2}}\to\frac{z^2}{(4-z)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)z^{n+2}}{4^{n+2}}$$
and for $|z|>4$ similarly: $$\frac{z^2}{(4-z)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)4^n}{z^{n}}$$

Comment: So you agree that the OP's solution is correct?

Comment: Yes but with some minor corrections.... The radius on convergence should be exactly consider and the series should be calculated for each time...

Comment: Well, outside the radius of convergence you don't get a power series but a Laurent series, so I think implicitly assuming one is in the radius of convergence is okay.

Comment: Yes and something i attained is exactly it!

Comment: I'm not arguing with your calculation, just saying it's not relevant to the question since the OP specified power series.